# Mock a function call being used inside list's append

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a code like this:

```
def create_namespace():
    _create_foobar()
    _create_spamegg()

p = list()
p.append(create_namespace())
```

I need to mock _create_foobar and _create_spamegg (both defined in same file)and have been able to do so with normal patch, but when i run the test cases which is written like this:

```
from xyz import create_namespace
@patch('path.to.file._create_foobar', mock_func)
@patch('path.to.file._create_spamegg', mock_func)
def test_create_namespace():
    assert create_namespace() is None
```

I get the same error while running the test cases as i would have got i were not successful 
in mocking `_create_foobar and _create_spamegg`. If I comment out `p.append(create_namespace())`
the test cases run successfully. I have been trying things like `patch.object()`, using `patcher in setUp` but to no avail, Can this code be tested, Please suggest how this can be done?

Comment: where are those `_create_xxxxxx()` functions? In the same file as the above code?

Comment: yes in the same file

Comment: And what is the error you get? The AssertionError coming from `create_namespace() is None`?

Comment: error that would come as if i was unable to mock _create_foobar() or _create_spamegg()

Comment: That's strange. At first sight everything looks fine. It may be because of the `mock_func` you use to mock those functions? I think we would need to see more of the code you have.